# Python BeautifulSoup: Getting table elements based on color attribute

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some html that looks like this (this represents rows of data in a table)

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_ES&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:00&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_NQ&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;191&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:01&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I have code that grabs the color from each data set:

```
mrkt_stat = []
for td in site.findAll('td'):
 if 'bgcolor' in td.attrs:
  mrkt_stat.append(td.attrs['bgcolor'])
```

Printing this list will give me a list of all colors from each row of data, which is good.

I also have code that will grab the row data from each data set:

```
data = []
for row in site.findAll('tr'):
 cols = row.find_all('td')
 cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
 data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

This is also good and it returns a list of lists with each sublist being a row of data from the table I am scraping.

However, I want to append/combine this code so that it only adds info to the **data** list if the hex color code in the row set is '#55aa2a'

EDIT: The data needs to be returned stripped as I am inputting the returned list into a pandas DataFrame and this DataFrame is what will be presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the `td`'s in the rows using the `attrs={'tag': 'attr'}` parameter with `site.find_all()`:

```
for row in site.find_all('tr'):
if row.find_all('td', attrs={'bgcolor': '#55aa2a'}):
    data.append([str(td.text.strip()) for td in row.find_all('td')])
```

the `data` list should then contain only those elements with the selected `bgcolor`:

```
>>> print(data)
[['CME_ES', '07:58:46', 'Connected', '0', '0', '0', '0', '07:58:00', '--:--:--', '0', '0', '01:25:00', '22:00:00'], 
 ['CME_NQ', '07:58:46', 'Connected', '0', '0', '191', '0', '07:58:01', '--:--:--', '0', '0', '01:25:00', '22:00:00']]
```

Comment: Is it possible to strip all the data so that only the useful info shows? [<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_NQ&nbsp;</td>, 
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>, ...] This is what is returned, but only [CME_NQ, 07:58:46, ...] is needed

Comment: Yes, I see, good point, thanks for your feedback. Check the update.

Comment: Yes, the sublist for each row is what I am looking for

Comment: Alright it might work now. please check update again. thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to scrape the same info from this where a row did not have a bgcolor attr, how would that work? So if there was a line in a row set that looked like <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td> how would I take this NULL bgcolor value?

Comment: If I understand correctly, maybe just add an `else:
        data.append(None)`. a NULL value (`None` in python) would then be appended to the `data` list.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it generates an empty list after printing. I also tried `if 'bgcolor' not in td.attrs: mrkt_stat.append('N/A')` but this generates a list that is far too big

Comment: I don't understand what the final output should look like ... So you want to add to the list only ***if there does exist*** `bgcolor` ***and only if*** `'bgcolor'` equals `'#55aa2a', otherwise if there is `bgcolor` but ***it is not*** *that* color, then add an empty list to the `data` list? (Up to here this is what is in the original question). Now if `bgcolor` does ***not*** exist in the row, what should it add to the `data` list? Could you post an example output of the `data` list for this scenario? (Apologies for the bold text, I'm only using it to emphasize the logic)

Comment: Firstly, I am not concerned with the style of your message lol, so no worries there. Secondly, I posted as another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545448/python-bs-fetching-rows-with-and-without-color-attribute)

Comment: Okay great, yes you're right, this probably is better suited for a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
for row in site.findAll('tr'):
  if row.attrs['bgcolor'] != '#55aa2a': continue
  cols = row.find_all('td')
  data.append([ele.text.strip() for ele in cols if ele.text.strip()])
```

Comment: Issue with this is that the compiler does not recognize 'bgcolor' as a valid slice, so the line with the if statement fails

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single nested list comprehension:

```
data = [i.text for row in soup.find_all('tr') for i in row.find_all('td', {'bgcolor': '#55aa2a'})]
```

Returns:

```
['\xa0--:--:--\xa0', '\xa0--:--:--\xa0']
```

Comment: I like this, but I would need the entire row of data to be returned, i.e. [CME_NQ, 07:58:46, Connected, ...] needs to be displayed.