# Python BS: Fetching rows with and without color attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html that looks like this (this represents rows of data in a table, i.e the data between **tr** and **/tr** is one row in a table)

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_ES&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:00&nbsp;</td>
**<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>**
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_NQ&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;191&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:01&nbsp;</td>
**<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>**
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I have code that grabs the color from each row set:

```
mrkt_stat = []
for td in site.findAll('td'):
 if 'bgcolor' in td.attrs:
  mrkt_stat.append(td.attrs['bgcolor'])
```

Issue is that when the row set has no **bgcolor** attribute, no data is added to **mrkt_stat** list.

How do I scrape this so that even if a row has no bgcolor attr, it will still be added to the list as NULL or N/A?

It is useful to know that the bgcolor attr (that may or may not be present) will always appear in the 9th line of a row set whether that row has the attr or not (look at the html lines enclosed with **)

EDIT: Output should look like the following (a list of all color attrs from row 9 of each row set and display 'N/A' if there is no color attr present):

```
['#55aa2a',...,'N/A']
```

Comment: Please show what output you are trying to get for that HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this, albeit a rather long approach, but solves the issue nontheless

```
keys = []
for tr in site.find_all('br'):
    for td in site.find_all('tr'):
        if td in keys:
            pass
        else:
            keys.append(td)
del keys[:4]

for i in range(0, len(keys)):
    g = keys[i]
    color = []

    for line in g:
        color.append(line)

    del color[:17]

    check = []
    h = color[0]
    if 'bgcolor' in h.attrs:
        check.append(h['bgcolor'])
    else:
        check.append('N/A')
```

To summarize up to the line `h = color[0]` is where I store the 9th line of the row set into a variable `h` and then I check if the bgcolor is in the attributes of this tag. If it is, it gets added to the `check` list if not, then `'N/A'` gets added instead

GREATLY APPRECIATED if one can figure out how to shorten this approach though :)!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `else` statement to your `if` statement:

```
mrkt_stat = []

for td in site.findAll('td'):
    if 'bgcolor' in td.attrs:
        mrkt_stat.append(td.attrs['bgcolor'])
    else:
        mrkt_stat.append('N/A')
```

Comment: I've tried this, it causes the list to not populate at all. I have also tried `if 'bgcolor' not in td.attrs: mrkt_stat.append('N/A')` and that also fails

Comment: I am fond of that approach, but sadly python is not

Comment: You need to add some more code to your question so I can recreate the problem.

Comment: This is all the code and all the attempts I have tried. I only need to be able to do what is described above